# Ubuntu 21.04 dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg fails to build libdvdcss

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, compiling

I am trying to install libdvd_pkg to play DRM protected DVD's.
dpkg-reconfigure gives some clue that the problem is  with building libdvdcss2. Maybe my gcc version 10.3.0 is the problem? Is there any other way to install libdvdcss2 on Ubuntu 21.04?

The build log file follows

```
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg//libdvdcss2_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.build:

dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package libdvdcss
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.4.2-1~local
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Sebastian Ramacher <sramacher@debian.org>
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source: info: using options from build/debian/source/options: --compression=xz
 debian/rules clean
I: libdvdcss_1.4.2
dh clean --parallel --with autoreconf
dh: warning: Compatibility levels before 10 are deprecated (level 9 in use)
   dh_auto_clean -O--parallel
dh_auto_clean: warning: Compatibility levels before 10 are deprecated (level 9 in use)
   dh_autoreconf_clean -O--parallel
   dh_clean -O--parallel
dh_clean: warning: Compatibility levels before 10 are deprecated (level 9 in use)
 debian/rules build
I: libdvdcss_1.4.2
dh build --parallel --with autoreconf
dh: warning: Compatibility levels before 10 are deprecated (level 9 in use)
   dh_update_autotools_config -O--parallel
   dh_autoreconf -O--parallel
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:18: installing './compile'
configure.ac:13: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_configure
make[1]: Går til katalog "/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build"
I: libdvdcss_1.4.2
dh_auto_configure -- --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-silent-rules
dh_auto_configure: warning: Compatibility levels before 10 are deprecated (level 9 in use)
    ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-silent-rules
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)



**checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details**

    tail -v -n \+0 config.log
==> config.log <==
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libdvdcss configure 1.4.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-silent-rules

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = arn-X570-UD
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.11.0-37-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 20 16:39:20 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2381: checking build system type
configure:2395: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2415: checking host system type
configure:2428: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2465: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2533: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2544: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2599: result: yes
configure:2745: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2784: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2791: checking for gawk
configure:2807: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2818: result: gawk
configure:2829: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2851: result: yes
configure:2880: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2897: result: yes
configure:3024: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3033: result: no
configure:3057: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3074: result: yes
configure:3132: checking how to print strings
configure:3159: result: printf
configure:3184: checking whether make supports the include directive
configure:3199: make -f confmf.GNU && cat confinc.out
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build'
this is the am__doit target
configure:3202: $? = 0
configure:3221: result: yes (GNU style)
configure:3291: checking for gcc
configure:3307: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3318: result: gcc
configure:3547: checking for C compiler version
configure:3556: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3567: $? = 0
configure:3556: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-gDeRY6/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-gDeRY6/gcc-10-10.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.3.0 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 
... rest of stderr output deleted ...
configure:3567: $? = 0
configure:3556: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3567: $? = 1
configure:3556: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3567: $? = 1
configure:3587: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3609: gcc -O2 -g0 -march=native -pipe -fomit-fame-pointer -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fomit-fame-pointer'; did you mean '-fomit-frame-pointer'?
configure:3613: $? = 1
configure:3651: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libdvdcss"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libdvdcss"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libdvdcss 1.4.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html"
| #define PACKAGE "libdvdcss"
| #define VERSION "1.4.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3656: error: in `/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build':
configure:3658: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-O2 -g0 -march=native -pipe -fomit-fame-pointer'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} '\''/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/missing'\'' aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE='#'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
APIDOC_FALSE=''
APIDOC_TRUE=''
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} '\''/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/missing'\'' autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} '\''/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/missing'\'' autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} '\''/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/missing'\'' automake-1.16'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-O2 -g0 -march=native -pipe -fomit-fame-pointer'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DOXYGEN=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
DVDCSS_LDFLAGS=''
DVDCSS_LTVERSION=''
DVDCSS_VERSION_MAJOR=''
DVDCSS_VERSION_MICRO=''
DVDCSS_VERSION_MINOR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GIT=''
GIT_FALSE=''
GIT_TRUE=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} '\''/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/missing'\'' makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libdvdcss'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='libdvdcss'
PACKAGE_STRING='libdvdcss 1.4.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libdvdcss'
PACKAGE_URL='https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.4.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
SYS_MSVC_FALSE=''
SYS_MSVC_TRUE=''
VERSION='1.4.2'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias='x86_64-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/share/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build/install-sh'
libdir='${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libexecdir='${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='/var'
mandir='${prefix}/share/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libdvdcss"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libdvdcss"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.4.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libdvdcss 1.4.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html"
#define PACKAGE "libdvdcss"
#define VERSION "1.4.2"

configure: exit 77
dh_auto_configure: error: ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-silent-rules returned exit code 77
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:13: override_dh_auto_configure] Fejl 25
make[1]: Forlader katalog "/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/build"
make: *** [debian/rules:10: build] Fejl 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

Comment: Pages and pages of  unreadable text and most likely nothing to do with the question. You need to clean this up so it can be read and then maybe someone can help.

Comment: Get a usable gcc : `sudo apt install build-essential` . ......... I.e. an install of gcc only will not install libc6-dev, linux-libc-dev, etc.  which will make gcc work fully.

Comment: It is already installed: build-essential/hirsute,now 12.8ubuntu3 amd64 [Installeret]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten that at some point I've set some compiler flags in my .bashrc
Haven't investigated wich flag(s) is the source of the problem, but removing them all seems to correct the problem. I know it wasn't the -j flag though, that was of course my first thought.

Thanks for your help and sorry for the disturpence.

For your information the flags set was:

```
# export CFLAGS="-O2 -g0 -march=native -pipe -fomit-fame-pointer"
# export CXXFlAGS="$CFLAGS"
# export MAKEFLAGS="-j11"
```